# How to make a menu to bind keys

Tags: c#, menu

I want to create a field (textbox, button, label ...) that when selected and pressed a key, take the name of the key.

I'm trying this without success:

```
private void label24_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    label24.Text += e.KeyData.ToString();
}
```

Edit1:

[My menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84IHk.jpg)

Currently I need to manually enter the keycode in the textbox, I would like to click on the field and press a key, the textbox.text change to the key code

Comment: Hello, could you provide more code, related to your question, please? Now it's not clear what are you trying to do

Comment: Still confused, but let's try. Why you can't add KeyDownEvent to your TextBox, then in this event you should change label24.Text with e.Key

Comment: I'm still a beginner, just change the Click event through KeyDown?

Comment: The problem is that you didn't provide enough information about the environment where the code is running. If it's WPF I would suggest to you use View Models and Text binding, if it's WinForm then you should add KeyDown event to your TextBox where you type information which should be displayed in the label. In this KeyDown event you should update Label Text

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking on how to bind key when user press it over Touch screen monitor, below is the example.

```
private void label24_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    myButton btn = (myButton)sender;
    MyTextBox.Text += btn.Tag.ToString();
}
```

but if you want the iterate all the buttons in the field. See the example below

```
public partial class myNumpad : UserControl
{
    public myNumpad()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindControls(tableLayoutPanel2);
    }

    public void BindControls(TableLayoutPanel table)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= table.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= table.RowCount; j++)
            {
                Control c = table.GetControlFromPosition(i, j);
                if (c is myButton)
                    c.Click += new EventHandler(Numpad_Click);
            }
        }
    }

    [BindableAttribute(true), Category("Control"), Description("SetControl")]
    public Control SetControl { get; set; }

    private void Numpad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SetControl != null)
        {
            myButton btn = (myButton)sender;
            SetControl.Text += btn.Tag.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

hope that will help.